# MongoDB - утилита mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

Пытаюсь импортировать базу данных таким способом (среда Ubuntu 12.04):

mongoimport -d USA -c cities --file http://media.mongodb.org/zips.org

Выскакивает ошибка: file doesn't exist. В чем проблема ?
Команду выполняю в терминале.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) скачайте этот файл 
*например:*

```
wget http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json
```

2) затем импортируйте

```
mongoimport -d USA -c cities --file zips.json
```